# KDE Connect can't see the other device while Wireguard VPN is enabled

Tags: networking, vpn, wireguard

My setup is as follows:

- Debian/KDE laptop computer, connected to the local network with local IP `192.168.178.25`
- Raspberry Pi, connected to the local network with local IP `192.168.178.35` AND runnning a wireguard server in which the Pi itself has a wireguard-IP of `10.117.42.1/24`
- Fritz box modem-router, being the gateway of the LAN at IP `192.168.178.1`. The upstream DNS of the fritz box is the `192.168.178.35 (aka the raspberry)` as the raspberry runs PiHole
- Android phone, connecting to the internet via wireguard, having a wireguard IP of `10.117.42.2/24`, a wireguard DNS of `192.168.178.35`, `AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::0/0`.

If I start the KDE program either on the laptop or the phone, they can't see each other. Even by manually typing addresses, they can't find each other. Obviously, if I disable the wireguard VPN on the phone and connect both the laptop and the phone to the same WiFi network, everything works as expected.

From my android phone, I can very well access webservers hosted on the raspberry, meaning that I have access to the whole LAN. So why can't the KDE connect program see the laptop at 192.168.178.25?

[POST SCRIPTUM] Why isn't my laptop connecting as a peer in the wireguard network? That's because if I am outside and I need to acces the local network from the laptop, I can just create a mobile hotspot from my phone, using its wireguard connection.